# Dynamic column of one2many fields in odoo v.13

Tags: dynamic, field, odoo-13

I almost try all the possibilities about this but I failed. Anyone can know if its possible? or any suggestion how to do it or any sites to read or modules to follow? Thank you in advance.

The problem is this ..

I have here a one2many fields in table.one.

[image]

As you can see I added two records/rows.

that two records will be the basis on how many columns will appear in one2many fields in table.two.

This will be my expected output in one2many fields on table.two.

[image]

I tried to override the fields_view_get. I only added a label and change the string of a fields but I don't know how to add fields.

Please help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't show fields by number in odoo tree. Odoo requires you to already have a defined view with all the fields that you want to show.

How ever you can work a round this by making conditions in the field with the attrs attribute. See the below example (Not tested before just an idea poped to my mind)

```
<record id="example_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">example.model.form</field>
    <field name="model">example.model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <!-- ... -->
            <field name="your_one2many_field">
                <tree>
                    <field name="field1" attrs="{'invisible':[('count','<',1)]}"/>
                    <field name="field2" attrs="{'invisible':[('count','<',2)]}"/>
                    <field name="field3" attrs="{'invisible':[('count','<',2)]}"/>
                    <!-- etc -->
                </tree>
            </field>
            <!-- ... -->
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```